# Cases of edited title not visible on search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Normally editing a title will update the search results a few seconds later.

But exceptionally, for a few questions, the new title is still not searchable months later, while the old title is.

Example with [question 40196046](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196046/sql-comma-seprated-string?s=1|15.1390), edited 3 months ago:

- [search on old title with `seprated`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22sql+comma+seprated+string%22), it returns question 40196046
- [search on new title with `separated`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22sql+comma+separated+string%22), it does not return question 40196046

I could give a couple of more examples, but my concern is not to fix those one by one. I'd like to know if it possible to:

- Analyze what happened
- Fix the issue if any
- And rebuild the cache of all titles of the database

If it is not easy to fix automatically for all the questions of Stack Exchange, do you suggest to re-apply manual edits on known affected questions, or not?

Note that this caching issue of titles in search results does not affect the auto-generated preview of titles when copy-pasting raw links, as in "[SQL comma separated String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196046/sql-comma-seprated-string?s=1|15.1390)".

---

Other examples of search cache issue:

- [question 33309842](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309842/need-search-a-value-from-database-from-comma-seprated-string)
- [question 20374096](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374096/cannot-get-attributes-separately-in-the-xml-file-in-eclipselink-moxy)
- [question 40858488](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858488/can-a-database-table-refer-to-itself-with-2-foreing-keys) is deleted but still searchable
- [question 40432831](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432831/php-mysql-username-and-password-database-check-failing-when-using-and-but-not-se?s=15|2.9921) is deleted but still searchable

Comment: Can you share the instances where you found this issue? Because based on one occurrence I would simple call this a glitch and I've checked around 50 title edits by you with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/652134) and I can't find any more then just that single case.  With just one incident it is hard to spot a pattern.

Comment: @rene I've added an example of deleted question which is still visible in the search cache. I don't know when was the deletion, as I'm less than 10k.

Comment: The deleted question is roomba-ed: *deleted by Community♦ Dec 31 '16 at 15:35 (RemoveDeadQuestions)*.  It looks like staleness of the search index.

Comment: Another edit now (in body) caused the change to take effect and title to be searchable. Something is obviously off though. It's not caching, it's something with the search index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rebuilding the index/cache of all posts in the database was performed yesterday by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301293/263422), so past issues are now solved.

Also, from now we are using Elastic 5.6.1 instead of Elastic Search 4.