# Are there Elastic Search indexing issues currently?

Tags: support, search, elasticsearch

Various edits I made in the past 30 minutes are not visible in Search Results.

Normally it takes less than thirty seconds to update.

Example: [This search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Achagning) should return no result at all now, yet it gives 5 results at this time.

Note that [I reported a similar issue 5 months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293199/cases-of-edited-title-not-visible-on-search), but it was for rare isolated posts. Today all the edits seem affected.

[edit]
Seems fixed, about a bit more than an hour later.

[next day]
Same issue today with [this search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aeclise).

[edit]
Seems fixed, quite more than three hours later. See Nick Craver's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is intentional, While low impact there isn't *zero* impact to our full index rebuilds. We're currently re-indexing Stack Overflow completely in the New York data center in order to prepare it for an Elastic 5.6.1 upgrade later this week. Search will return to normal (near real-time indexing) in a few hours.

Status for the curious:
[image: Indexing Status]

I've tweeted and relayed through Stack Status since this is user-impacting. Honestly we thought you guys and gals wouldn't notice...but here we are.

Comment: Oh, whoah, Elastic 5! So the following old issue will be solved as well? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327327/abnormally-long-summaries-in-search/327857#327857

Comment: I have honestly forgotten about that, but yes! We'll be sure to test it and report back.

Comment: Nice interface. All yours, or something pre-built inside Elastic?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd just something we made to watch indexing status. It's a local status object updated in-memory and published to redis (via protobuf) for observation across the infrastructure.